# How to filter by list of values in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, filter

How can I filter the objects in Django Admin by list of values entered by user in a text field?

For example - a user would input a list of IDs separated by commas and the Django Admin should return all the objects that match those IDs?

Answer (score 0):

This is concept, so you should change it to your needs

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id']
    search_fields = ['id']

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        if search_term != '': # This chek needed if you additionaly use SimpleListFilter, otherwise SimpleListFilter would be broken
            search_term = map(int, search_term.split(',')) #not integers in search_term will result in an error
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(id__in = search_term)
        return queryset.distinct(), use_distinct #adding distinct() or objects duplicates could appear
```

Result in my project

[image]